# Require specific login for Wordpress REST API endpoints

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

Is there a "simple" way to require specific logins for certain Wordpress REST API endpoints? Specifically, I don't want just anyone who is logged in to be able to post, view users, update users, (and more) with the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

The "simple" options are these two:

#### 1. Permissions Callback

For custom routes and endpoints, in the [Permissions Callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback) of the WordPress REST API, use functions like [current_user_can](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) to permit or deny access to data.

#### 2. rest_api_init hook

For all REST API routes, the [rest_api_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_api_init/) action hook fires when preparing to serve a REST API request. Verification checks can be made here.

---

The more involved options include extending the [WP_REST_Controller](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/) class.